# PHP - How to get the text from multiple p tags in a row

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a variable holding some html. In the html there are several p tags next to each other. I'd like to retrieve the text from those p tags and format them into 1 paragraph and set this new paragraph to a new variable. Does that make sense?

```
<h2></h2>
<p>date</p>
<ul></ul>
<iframe></iframe>
<p>apple</p>
<p>banana</p>
<p>grape</p>
<ul></ul>
```

becomes:

```
<p>apple banana grape</p>
```

NOTE: the elements in the html may vary a bit. No iframe for example. An image somewhere, etc.

Comment: [regex should/can not be used to parse HTML.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: You can remove the HTML tags with [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags)

Comment: @ orourkrk, I see. My knowledge of php is limited as I am a font end programmer but I've started learning PHP. The page you linked to has several suggestions instead of regex, can you suggest which among them is the preferred solution for my case?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Xpath to do that

```
$html = '<h2></h2>
<p>date</p>
<ul></ul>
<iframe></iframe>
<p>apple</p>
<p>banana</p>
<p>grape</p>
<ul></ul>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->query("//p");
foreach ($elements as $node){
echo $node->nodeValue. "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
$html = '<h2></h2>
  <p>date</p>
  <ul></ul>
  <iframe></iframe>
  <p>apple</p>
  <p>banana</p>
  <p>grape</p>
  <ul></ul>';

if (preg_match_all('~<p>(?P<paragraphs>.*?)</p>~is', $html, $matches)) {
  print_r($matches['paragraphs']);
}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => date
    [1] => apple
    [2] => banana
    [3] => grape
)
```

P.S.
**"Smart" downvoters could you please comment why are you downvoting? :))))))))))))))**

P.P.S
**Special edition for those two who downvoted:**

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);
$paragraphs = $document->getElementsByTagName('p');
$result     = array();

foreach ($paragraphs as $paragraph) {
  $result[] = $paragraph->nodeValue;  
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: I have a feeling somebody is about to post this link with the comment "don't parse HTML with regex"... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags Using a DOMDocument is probably a better way

Comment: yes indeed! :D I posted a very similar answer to yours and got flamed for it!